# Why a NextJs application is adding some extra node modules config in package-lock.json after the NextJs app is launched?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, repository, node-modules, package-lock.json

I´ve a **NextJs** & **ReactJs** application built up with these libs:

```
    "next": "^13.3.1",
    "next-auth": "^4.20.1",
    "next-http-proxy-middleware": "^1.2.5",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
```

Let´s assume all dependencies listed in the project `package.json` are all installed with `npm install` and `package-lock.json` is updated. And `package.json` and `package-lock.json` are part of the project repository.

Once I run the **NextJs** application with the command `npx next dev` what happens is that at the end of `package-lock.json` these extra node module configuration are added.

```
    "node_modules/@next/swc-darwin-x64": { ... }
    "node_modules/@next/swc-linux-arm64-gnu": { ... }
    "node_modules/@next/swc-linux-arm64-musl": { ... }
    "node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-gnu": { ... }
    "node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-musl": { ... }
    "node_modules/@next/swc-win32-arm64-msvc": { ... }
    "node_modules/@next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc": { ... }
    "node_modules/@next/swc-win32-x64-msvc": {
      "version": "13.3.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@next/swc-win32-x64-msvc/-/swc-win32-x64-msvc-13.3.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Sl1F4Vp5Z1rNXWZYqJwMuWRRol4bqOB6+/d7KqkgQ4AcafKPN1PZmpkCoxv4UFHtFNIB7EotnuIhtXu3zScicQ==",
      "cpu": [
        "x64"
      ],
      "optional": true,
      "os": [
        "win32"
      ],
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 10"
      }
    }
```

I just copied fully, the last object for readability, but all these objects are more or less similar.

My question is, why is this happening, and shall I update and push to repo also this updated version of `package-lock.json`?

Thanks